# How to make a template for content type with panels

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, panels

I´ve created a content type "Products" with "N" fields and I try to create a template for this content type, each product should have its own page.

How I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Google searching I found this solution.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1422454

Best regards!